# Materials for growing large quality sugar crystals

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions

I am trying to grow large, solid, quality crystals on a course fabric, and I was wondering what other than sugar I would need to put in my solution, as well as how long it may take, and if food coloring/another dye would change the color of the crystals without destroying them. Any tips or advice would be great.

Comment: There is a nice book, about $10, on crystal growing. "Crystals and Crystal Growing" by Alan Holden, Phylis Morrison, Bert Singer
ISBN-10: 0262580500 ISBN-13: 9780262580502

Answer (score 1):

The [Exploratorium has directions for making **rock candy**](https://www.exploratorium.edu/cooking/candy/recipe-rockcandy.html), the common name for sucrose crystals. In short:

1. Make a saturated solution of sucrose -- 4 cups sugar dissolved in just 2 cups of *boiling* water.
2. Immerse the fabric in the solution, and let it cool *slowly* (to make larger crystals). You might use a covered styrofoam container to slow the cooling. If crystallization doesn't start in a few days, you might need to drop one seed crystal of sugar into the container.
3. You can experiment with different types of food color in the sugar solution to color the crystals, but in the process of crystallization, foreign molecules of dye may be excluded from the crystals. The larger the crystal, the less colored it may appear.

Enjoy! Be sure to use sanitary equipment and safe colors, if anyone is to eat this. BTW, ordinary cane sugar is one of the purest substances sold in quantity, better than 99.9% sucrose.